# NodeJs After a long period of inactivity Error: This socket has been ended by the other party

Tags: node.js, sockets, nginx, digital-ocean, node-mysql

I am using node-mysql https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql

This happens at random times, not quite sure what's triggering it. I received it  after a long period of inactivity  but doesn't always happen. here is the stack trace below:-

```
server-0 (err): Trace: AUTHENTICATION ERROR: Error: This socket has been ended by the other party. Auth: abcuser
server-0 (err):     at /var/www/dating/www/libs/authentication.js:36:17
server-0 (err):     at _rejected     (/var/www/dating/www/node_modules/q/q.js:807:24)
server-0 (err):     at /var/www/dating/www/node_modules/q/q.js:833:30
server-0 (err):     at Promise.when (/var/www/dating/www/node_modules/q/q.js:1077:31)
server-0 (err):     at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/var/www/dating/www/node_modules/q/q.js:751:41)
server-0 (err):     at /var/www/dating/www/node_modules/q/q.js:573:44
server-0 (err):     at flush (/var/www/dating/www/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
server-0 (err):     at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:415:9)
server-0 (err):     at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:385:13)
```

I am using restify server.

hosted on digital ocean configured with nginx and nodejs with proxy.

Any help?

Comment: This seems like normal behaviour - connection is terminated after a long time of inactivity.

Answer (score 1):

Some ways in which you can see this more in detail are:

1. Look at the time difference between connection and disconnection. See if it's consistent. Then check if there's a timeout setting for that specific amount of time. You could be hitting a timeout.
2. Use the `NODE_DEBUG` environment variable.

   `env NODE_DEBUG=* node yourprogram.js args`

   This will make node show internal traces such as what the sockets are doing. You can also scope that to specific modules, using `NODE_DEBUG=net,tls` instead of `*`
3. Use Wireshark, listen on that port and follow the stream. You can see what can be causing the disconnection. e.g: if a TCP packet with the RST flag is set, see which host sent it.